# MongoDB $geoNear aggregation pipeline (using query option and using $match pipeline operation) giving different no of results

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, 2dsphere

I am using a $geoNear as the first step in the aggregation framework. I need to filter out the results based on "tag" field and it works fine but I see there are 2 ways both giving different results.

**Sample MongoDB Document**

```
    {
      "position": [
        40.80143,
        -73.96095
      ],
      "tag": "pizza"
    }
```

I have added 2dsphere index to the "position" key

```
    db.restaurants.createIndex( { 'position' : "2dsphere" } )
```

**Query 1**

****uses $match aggregration pipeline operation to filter out the results based on "tag" key****

```
    db.restaurants.aggregate(
      [
       {
           "$geoNear":{

               "near": { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 55.8284,-4.207] },
               "limit":100,
               "maxDistance":10*1000,
               "distanceField": "dist.calculated",
               "includeLocs": "dist.location",
               "distanceMultiplier":1/1000,
               "spherical": true
        }
       },{
           "$match":{"tag":"pizza"}
       },

       {
          "$group":{"_id":null,"totalDocs":{"$sum":1}}
       }
      ]
    );
```

**Query 2**

***Uses query inside the $geoNear aggregation operation to filter results based on "tag" key***

```
    db.restaurants.aggregate(
      [
       {
           "$geoNear":{
               "query" : {"tag":"pizza"}
               "near": { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 55.8284,-4.207] },
               "limit":100,
               "maxDistance":10*1000,
               "distanceField": "dist.calculated",
               "includeLocs": "dist.location",
               "distanceMultiplier":1/1000,
               "spherical": true
        }
       },
       {
          "$group":{"_id":null,"totalDocs":{"$sum":1}}
       }
      ]
    );
```

The grouping option is just to get the count of documents returned by both the queries.

The totalDocs returned by both queries seem to be different.

Can someone explain me the differences between both the queries ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Few assumptions:-***  
 1. Assume there are 300 records that match based on the location. 
 2. Assume first set of 100 results do not have tag pizza. The rest 200 documents (101 to 300) have tag pizza

***Query 1:-***

- There are 2 pipeline operations $geoNear and $match
- The output of $geoNear pipeline operation is the input to $match
  pipeline operation
- $geoNear finds max of 100 results (limit we have specified) based on
  the location sorted by nearest to far distance.  (Note here that the
  100 results retured are purely based on the location. So these 100
  results do not contain any document with tag "pizza")
- These 100 results are sent to the next pipeline operation $match from
  where the filtering happens. But since the first set of 100 results
  did not have tag pizza, the  output is empty

***Query 2:-***

- There is only 1 pipeline operation $geoNear
- There is a query field included in the $geoNear pipeline operation
  $geoNear finds max of 100 results (limit we have specified) based on
  the location sorted by nearest to far distance and the query
  tag=pizza
- Now here the results from 101 to 200 are returned as output as the
  query is included within the pipeline operation $geoNear. So in
  simple sentence we say, find all documents with location [x,y] with
  tag=pizza.

P.S : - The $group pipeline stage is added just for getting the count and hence have not written about it in the explaination

Answer (score 3):

```
// If you have to apply multiple criteria to find locations then this query might helpful

 const userLocations = await userModel.aggregate([
            {
                $geoNear: {
                    near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [data.lon1,data.lat1] 
                      },//set the univercity points
                    spherical: true,
                    distanceField: "calcDistance",
                    // maxDistance: 2400,//25km 
                    "distanceMultiplier": 0.001,
                   
                }
            },
            { $unwind: "$location" }, 
            { $match: {
                "location": {
                  $geoWithin: {
                    $centerSphere: [
                      [ 73.780553, 18.503327], 20/ 6378.1        //check the user point is present here
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }},
        

        ])
```