# MongoDB Different response on different environment[Aggregate]

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the next query:

```
db.getCollection('dealers').aggregate([{ "$geoNear" : { "near" : { "type" : "Point" , "coordinates" : [ 22.937506 , -30.559482]} , "spherical" : true , "distanceField" : "distance" , "maxDistance" : 21000000 , "num" : 6}}, { "$match" : { "$and" : [ { "brands" : { "$in" : [ "starbucks"]}} , { "country" : "za"} , { "language" : "en"}]}},{ $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }, { "$limit" : 6}]);
```

I have two environments, the two environments have the same data and the same indexes, but when I run the above query, I get the first environment 6 registers and for the another 3 registers.

I checked and they have the same mongoDB version, Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: how do you know that data is totally same?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I checked the two DBs and this is the same, I compared with this tool https://www.diffchecker.com/diff

Comment: No @SergeyBerezovskiy means how can you be sure mongodb DATA same in both DBs ?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy you were in the right, they have different data, thanks for your helping. I find that my problem is because first is done the $gear and after that $match.  Do you know How could I put first the $match and after $gear

Comment: guys, mi problem was solved with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173956/mongodb-geonear-aggregation-pipeline-using-query-option-and-using-match-pipel?rq=1
thanks.